# Registered user check for lowercase or uppercase

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform

I want to know how to check the existing users for either upper or lowercase when a new user is signing up. At present for example the followig two users can be registered

tom and Tom, both of these are considered as two separate users, so if this happens I want to sound off to the user that the username already exists. Where in code exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a textwatcher for the edittext where user enters loginname and when focus changes from the edittext get the string in there using getText and pass this to an api which will check the username with db to check for similarity and will return a status false if similar user exits and you can show a red underline or red hidden badge to side of the edittext on the basis of this result to notify the user that such a username already exists.